# What should I use instead of localhost to deploy a React App?

Tags: reactjs, localhost, web-deployment, contact-form

Please, I have this piece of code for a Contact Form in a React APP.
It works fine locally, but after I deploy it doesn't work. I guess I have change the localhost for something else, but for what?

**Let's say that my domain is https://www.something.com.
What should I use instead of localhost to deploy my React App?**

Error message that I receive if I keep the localhost domain: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

PS.: The website works perfectly as well (locally and after the deploy). What I am trying here is to receive an answer of my fetch method (for my contact form) that it's not working.

```js
fetch('http://localhost:5500/contact', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',   
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(details),
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever server backend you are running on port 5500 needs to be hosted online too. At the moment you just have your frontend hosted.

Once you have your backend hosted, change your fetch URL to that instead.

Comment: Thanks, man! Your answer helped me to see some light at the end of the tunnel. I am still studying it more to understand it better! It was helpful and I really appreciate that! :)

Answer (score -1):

have you added the homepage props into the package.json file.?

Comment: Yes, I did it. Actually, now I realized that I forgot to describe this: the website works perfectly too. What I am trying to receive an answer of my fetch method (in my contact form) that it's not working.